# compare two Lists of objects and return a list which has common objects in two

Tags: java

I have two lists -

```
ArrayList<MyObject> list1 -> [obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, obj5, obj6]

ArrayList<MyObject>  list2 -> [obj1, obj6, obj7, obj8]
```

Is there any utility method already existing in java api which can give a list of only common records of two?

expected list ->
`[obj1, obj6]`

MyObject looks like this -

```
class MyObject {
  public Integer number;
  public String name;
  public Integer parent;
  public String parentName;
}
```

I only need to use `number` and `name` to do the comparison.

---

i am aware of approach using `retainAll` or `removeAll` to get the desired list. The problem however is, **I cannot override `equals` method of `MyObject` as it is used for some different purpose**. And the `retainAll` or `removeAll` method doesn't seems to accept `Comparator` object.

I know another solution is to iterate through the lists and find the common ones. I am looking if there is already some method which do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any cleaner way than what you already suggest.

However, if you need equality but can't use `equals` (I'm not going to ask ;) you could merge the lists and sort them, and then compare manually each element to the next, keeping only the duplicate ones.

Comment: its so disappointing that `java.util.List` methods does not have overloaded method taking `Comparator`. Anyways, I created a seperate utility method which takes a Comparator and added all the dirty code in it, so maybe i can reuse the same later when required..... btw thanks for your suggestion! it fits well to the requirement.

Comment: @Kshitij hmm I don't know what your exact requirements are, and I'm sure you have good reasons, but you're kind of the one that went against the flow by using the `equals` method for something that wasn't equals ;) Just be careful that you don't use anything else that also relies on equals, it might be a hard to track bug!

Comment: Actually `equals` method in my case also is used to compare 2 entities as we normally do,  the scenario above is a special case where i need to compare only few fields. I should have indicated earlier itself that the `MyObject` i showed above is just a sample, and not the actual object, the actual object is way bigger and has completely different fields.

Comment: Equals is for equality, not for selection or matching.  Sounds like you are checking that something "matches" or "satisfies" a condition, which isn't equality.  It is equality if the item can be _replaced_ by the other, without anyone knowing the difference.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the same value from two list, I give you a string example:

```
/**
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // create a script engine manager

    List<String> list_1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    list_1.add("a");
    list_1.add("b");
    List<String> list_2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    list_2.add("a");
    list_2.add("b");
    list_2.add("c");
    System.out.println(getSameVaue(list_2,list_1));
}

public static List<String> getSameVaue(List<String> list1,
        List<String> list2) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (list1.size() > list2.size()) {
        for (String s : list1) {
            if (list2.contains(s)) {
                result.add(s);
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (String s : list2) {
            if (list1.contains(s)) {
                result.add(s);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

But if you want to use your Object, please do not forget implement **equals** method.